# What other options besides ifupdown are there for general users/sys-admin?

Tags: debian, networking

Yesterday, I was upgrading packages and came across [NEWS.gz in netbase 5.4](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/n/netbase/netbase_5.4_changelog):

> netbase (5.4) unstable; urgency=medium
>
> - Stopped recommending ifupdown because nowadays there are options.
>     For the time being it will still be installed by default because it
>     has important priority. (Closes: #824884)

What other options are there? I looked up [the bug mentioned therein](https://bugs.debian.org/824884) but found nothing about any other tools.

Can somebody share what tools the DD/DM might be talking about?

I use ifup and ifdown to clear any temporary ethernet networking issues and it works most of the time:

```
$ sudo ifdown eth0
```

This clears all and any dhcp leases

```
$ sudo ifup eth0
```

After half a minute to a minute, do this to make sure you get a new lease and are in business.

At times, when I'm not using Internet for much, I do use

```
$ ping debian.org
```

in one of the VT (virtual Console Terminals) to make sure things are moving along.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two other main networking tools nowadays on Linux are [Network Manager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager/) and [systemd-networkd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd.html).

`ifupdown` isn't going away yet, the change in `netbase` is just cleanup: there's no reason for it to recommend networking tools (considering recommendations as defined in Debian Policy), and removing the recommendation is safe because default installations still end up with `ifupdown` installed. Cleaning such dependencies up will simplify possible future switches to other default tools.

Answer (score 6):

You may use

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down 
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

If you have wireless interface use

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: This isn't a complete replacement for `ifup`/`ifdown`: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27166

Comment: The `ifconfig` command is also deprecated in favor of the iproute2 package. The recommended alternatives are: `sudo ip link set eth0 down` and `sudo ip link set eth0 up` respectively.

Comment: Serious question. How is "ip link set eth0 up", i.e. typing 5 words which I can't auto-complete, better than just "ifup eth0"?