# why is netbase removing some services?

Tags: debian

I shared [another](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335944/what-other-options-besides-ifupdown-are-there-for-general-users-sys-admin/) query a while ago. @StephenKitt shared and I quote

> there's no reason for it to recommend networking tools (considering
>   recommendations as defined in Debian Policy), and removing the
>   recommendation is safe because default installations still end up with
>   ifupdown installed. Cleaning such dependencies up will simplify
>   possible future switches to other default tools. -Stephen Kitt

Now while I can understand that, what is needed to know are possible replacements. For instance it has removed three services which are essential to me. I do understand that they will be installed as default but still -

> - services: removed ssh (22/udp).
> - services: removed http (80/udp), https (443/udp).

from /usr/share/doc/netbase

While we do hope that web server providers will make https a default offering either with tying up with multiple certificate providers at low-cost or something, as of now it's upto the site creator to do the way s/he wants to set up. Don't see that changing soon.

Similarly I don't know anything better than ssh ?

```
[$] ssh -v localhost

OpenSSH_7.3p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

I am ok with the changes being proposed, **just need to know what changes** (if any) are going to become defaults so I can work that out.

Comment: This reads more like a rant. Would you be able to clarify the post?

Comment: It is not a rant. It is trying to understand what changes could be coming which make the above services obsolete. Usually removal of services signal what the devs. are thinking about, so trying to get more insight on whatever proposed changes might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The removals are only removals of service *definitions* from [`/etc/services`](https://salsa.debian.org/md/netbase/blob/master/etc-services). The definitions were removed because they were obsolete or unused:

- [SSH over UDP](https://salsa.debian.org/md/netbase/commit/c9decbcc471217a6598ff968d348f30f36912853) isn't used (this still leaves a service definition for SSH over TCP)
- [HTTP and HTTPS over UDP](https://salsa.debian.org/md/netbase/commit/5a484e2c08ca0f53bdf552780f7bfd4fc6994647) aren't used (leaving HTTP and HTTPS over TCP)

etc. (read the [git log](https://salsa.debian.org/md/netbase/commits/master) for details of all the changes).

This only affects short-hand service definitions, and even then only unused service definitions, nothing else. It doesn't affect dependencies, the *availability* of services (which are provided by other packages anyway), your ability to provide services, etc.

Comment: thanx, that cleared lot of confusion in my mind.